# How do I fix blank pygame screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a basic pong pygame and I have coded my main.py, paddle.py, and ball.py files and unfortunately, when I run the game it only displays a black pygame window.  My paddles, ball, net, and score are not visible... it's just blank.
[Screenshot of Blank/Black Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxV1y.png)

The following is my code, I have seperated it by each file.

I cannot seem to find what is causing this error so any feedback would be appreciated.

MAIN.PY

```
# Import pygame library and initialize the game engine 
import pygame
from paddle import Paddle
from ball import Ball

pygame.init()

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

# Open a new window
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

paddleA = Paddle(WHITE, 10, 100)
paddleA.rect.x = 20
paddleA.rect.y = 200

paddleB = Paddle(WHITE, 10, 100)
paddleB.rect.x = 670
paddleB.rect.y = 200

ball = Ball(WHITE, 10, 10)
ball.rect.x = 345
ball.rect.y = 195

# This will be a list that contains all the sprites we intend to use in game.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Add paddles to the list of sprites
all_sprites_list.add(paddleA)
all_sprites_list.add(paddleB)
all_sprites_list.add(ball)

# Loop will carry on until user exits the game (ex. clicks the close button)
carryOn = True

# Clock will be used to control how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize player scores
scoreA = 0
scoreB = 0 

# ----- Main Program Loop -----
while carryOn:
    # --- Main Event Loop ---
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # user did something
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT: # if user clicked close
            carryOn==False # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_x: # Pressing the x key will quit the game
                carryOn==False

    # Moving the paddles when the user uses the arrow keys (Player A),
    # or W/S keys (Player B)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        paddleA.moveUp(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        paddleA.moveDown(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddleB.moveUp(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddleB.moveDown(5)
        
    # --- Game Logic ---
    all_sprites_list.update()

    # Checks if the ball is bouncing against any of the 4 walls
    if ball.rect.x>=690:
        ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
    if ball.rect.x<=0:
        ball.velocity[0] = -ball.velocity[0]
    if ball.rect.y>490:
        ball.velocity[1] = -ball.velocity[1]
    if ball.rect.y<0:
        ball.velocity[1] = -ball.velocity[1]

    #Detect collisions between the ball and the paddles
    if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, paddleA) or pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, paddleB):
      ball.bounce()

# --- Drawing Code ---

# clears the screen to black
screen.fill(BLACK)

# draws the net
pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [349, 0], [349, 500], 5)

# Draws all sprites in one go (I only have 2 for now)
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

# Display scores
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 74)
text = font.render(str(scoreA), 1, WHITE)
screen.blit(text, (250,10))
text.font.render(str(scoreB), 1, WHITE)
screen.blit(text (420,10))

# update screen with what we've drawn
pygame.display.flip()

# limit to 60 frames per second
clock.tick(60)

# Once we have exited the main program loop we stop the game engine
pygame.quit()
```

PADDLE.PY

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0,0,0)

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # This class represents a paddle.  It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the paddle and it's x and y position (width nd height).
        # Set the background color as transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        # Draw the paddle which is a rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0,0, width, height])

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
        # Check that you are not going too far (off screen)
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
        # Check that you are not going too far (off screen)
        if self.rect.y > 400:
            self.rect.y = 400
```

BALL.PY

```
import pygame
from random import randint
BLACK = (0,0,0)
 
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #This class represents a ball. It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        
        # Pass in the color of the ball, its width and height.
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
 
        # Draw the ball (a rectangle!)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        
        self.velocity = [randint(4,8),randint(-8,8)]
        
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.rect.y += self.velocity[1]

    def bounce(self):
        self.velocity[0] = -self.velocity[0]
        self.velocity[1] = randint(-8,8)
```

Comment: Have you previously been able to write any kind of Pygame code at all which doesn't have the problem? If yes, then the actual challenge is to figure out why this code doesn't live up to that standard - in which case you should start by reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , and by trying to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of the problem. Otherwise, you need to figure out how to make Pygame display anything at all, which is best answered by consulting the documentation and trying out the examples.

Answer (score 0):

**You are simply not flipping the screen in the main loop, in the main file.**
All is actually being updated, but nothing is being rendered on the screen.

Just intend the code from

```
# --- Drawing Code ---
```

to

```
clock.tick(60)
```

I think you forgot to indent it.

Just be careful not to include `pygame.quit()` in the main loop.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a tabulation layer from

```py
...
# --- Drawing Code --- 
...
```

to end in main.py